# How can I add a third fadeIn effect in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I followed a tutorial and got a fadeIn effect working in HTML with Javascript and no CSS

This sounds really dumb but I have no Idea how can I make the second step to fade to a third step

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#weiter').click(function() {

            $('#age option:selected').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "no") alert('Why.');
                if ($(this).val() == "under") alert('Hallo');
                if ($(this).val() == "ok") {
                    $('#step1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $('#step2').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

        <div id="step1">
            Hello
            <p align="center">
                <input id="weiter" class="btn" type="button" value="Next&raquo;">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="step2">
            Welcome
            <p align="center">
                <input id="weiter" class="btn" type="button" value="Next&raquo;">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="step3">
            Bye
        </div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: I added $('#step3').fadeIn('fast'); but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could do:

```
$('#step1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('#step2').fadeIn('fast', function(){
        $('#step3').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Also, there are many plugins for doing this kind of sequential animations. Full discosure; one of those are mine. I created it a while back when I had the same problem: https://github.com/fillswitch/Jquery-Sequential-Animations

Comment: hmmm when I press the "next" button now nothing shows up, as I'm not allowed to use a plugin as my boss thinks they are all keyloggers

Comment: @ekclone - Sounds like your boss is a moron.

Comment: Lol. You could also just copy the code from my plugin's files :P

Comment: Also, its a little hard to troubleshoot with a JS Fiddle when we're missing some HTML; namely this `#age` element. Could you provide a JS fiddle? Or at least more HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#step1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
       $('#step2').fadeIn('fast', function() {

                 $('#step2').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                                $('#step3').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                                });
                });

        });
});
```

Try this